# Error in exporting data with headers - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the below script for exporting data from table, which is working completely fine.

```
declare @sql varchar(8000)
select @sql = 'bcp "Select * from [CV18].dbo.ZMM002" queryout D:\Share\Vendor_portal_Pending_IBD\bcptest.txt -c -t^| -T -S'+ @@servername
exec  master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

But I want to add headers to it. I have found out a way to do that by using UNION ALL with header names.

```
select 'Counter','External_ID','Delivery_Date','Transport_ID','Bill_of_Lading','Delivery_Item','Material','Delivery_QTY',
'Unit','PO_Number','PO_Item'
union all 
select * from ZMM002
```

But how can I add this union all query in my bcp query?

I get a syntax error, because I am using single quotes (') in union all query, which is cutting off the outer single quote, i.e @sql = ' '

Comment: You need to escape quotes. Quotes are escaped by doubling them up i.e.' -> '' e.g. `select 'Counter','External_ID', ....` -> `'select ''Counter'',''External_ID'', ....'`

Comment: Thanks that is all i needed

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is better to do this as a post-op.

Export two files, one with the header, the other with the actual data. Afterwards, concatenate the two files using the `COPY` command.

Suppose you exported to `header.txt` and `data.txt`, the command would be

```
COPY /b "\\path\header.txt"+"\\path\data.txt" "\\path\data.dat"
```

Where `\\path` would be your actual path.

---

If you're formatting the header SQL, double the qoutes:

```
SET @sql='select ''Counter'',''External_ID'',''Delivery_Date'',''Transport_ID'',''Bill_of_Lading'',''Delivery_Item'',''Material'',''Delivery_QTY'',''Unit'',''PO_Number'',''PO_Item''';
```